# Command raised an exception: IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence DISCORD.PY

Tags: python, list, discord.py, member

````
```
async def randomtokick(ctx):
    anychannel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel.id
    voice_channel = client.get_channel(anychannel)
    # Join the voice channel
    member_to_kick: discord.Member = random.choice(voice_channel.members)
    voice_client: discord.VoiceClient = await voice_channel.connect()
    await ctx.send(member_to_kick)
    await member_to_kick.edit(voice_channel = None)
```
````

I'm having troubles, because the bot apparently can't create a list of members which are in a voice channel, even when I tried it in a channel with 5 friends. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Intents are missing as the code works fine for me.

Make sure to turn them on in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) for your application.

**You can find them here:** *Navigate to your Application -> Bot -> Scroll down -> Make your ticks*

**To implement them to your code you can use the following:**

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all() # Imports all the Intents
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="YourPrefix", intents=intents) # Or whatever you use
```

***Or just the members Intent:***

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default() # Imports the default intents
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents) # Or whatever you defined/use
```